# Share variables among notebooks with different Kernels

Tags: variable-definitions, kernel-startup

So I have a server running in another notebook with a secondary kernel.
I run my main notebook and launch the server notebook, but I have configured the variables in my main one, and can't find a way to send variables from one to another.
I already tried something like:

```
ServerPort = 5000;
SetSharedVariable[ServerPort];
```

Then in another notebook:

```
%SharedVariables
{}
```

as you see there is nothing.

Another way to solve my problem would be to pass parameters between one and the other, I open the second one like this:

```
NotebookOpen[FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "server.nb"}];
```

Thanks in advance for your help, I already googled and found no related content, that is why I ask it to you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean bei "a server running in another notebook"?

Comment: I mean that I use a notebook to run something apart, say a server, so it needs to be in another kernel because it will be always running.

Comment: Are both kernels running on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, they are. But I must do it o different notebooks since the commands that i need to use are not compatible with Parallelize[] or ParallelEvaluate[] or any other

Comment: Well that's not how parallel evaluation works in Mathematica, see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ParallelTools/tutorial/Overview.html)

Comment: The thing is that I can not use Parallelize[] with JLink library, so I use different Notebooks with different kernels to run programs in parallel